# changing the value of a child input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am having troubles in changing the value of a hidden `<input>` after dropping a sortable element
Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuMtm/2/)

I Am trying to change the value of the hidden `<input>` that is inside the `block <div>` when i drop the  from the container

i have tried this but with no luck

```
$('.block1').on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
    var $list = $(this); 
     $(this).children().first("input").val = 'Something';

    if ($list.children().length > 2) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a method. So try this

```
$(this).children().first("input").val("Something");
```

Assuming the `$(this).children().first("input")` expression returns a valid object for your DOM

Comment: thanks Shyju, i didn't knew that the assignment of a new value was through the method itself, really appreciate your help

Comment: @ArwaSaad, You should pick this answer instead. The use of the `children` function makes sure that it will not be looking deeper in descendents. That makes it more robust if the dropped elements can ever contain their own inputs. It's also more efficient than `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//use .first() only if there are multiple input elements under `this` and you want to set the value to first item
$(this).find("input").first().val('Something');
```

Comment: However this will fail if the dropped elements have inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [**:hidden**](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
$(this).find('input:hidden').val('Something');
```

Please note that `.val = 'Something'` is not correct, you should use `.val('Something');`

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j678n/)